# Django get values from query set

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

How can I get individual values by field from a query set returned by a manager. The manager returns like:

```
return super(InvesteeManager, self).get_queryset().filter(id=3)
```

The result is : `[<Investee: Investee object>]` but I wish to get the individual values returned.

Comment: What do you mean by "individual values"? Do you mean content within each model instance, e.g. the values in the fields of the table?

Comment: Yes that's what I want...

Comment: They are just accessible from the individual model instances...

`investee.some_field_name`, `investee.some_other_field_name` etc

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
super(InvesteeManager, self).get_queryset().get(id=3)
```

Filter return a QuerySet, Get return an unique object.